# Collapse / Expand Click Groups with Angular DataTable

Tags: angular, typescript, datatables, angular-datatables

I'm using [Angular datatable](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) with Angular 8.
I'm trying to implement [this example](http://live.datatables.net/najufodu/1/edit) done with jQuery, but the problem is when I use row group in my code:

```
this.dtOptions = {
      order: [[2, 'asc']],
      rowGroup: {
        // Uses the 'row group' plugin
        dataSrc: 2,
        startRender: function (rows, group) {
            var collapsed = !!collapsedGroups[group];

            rows.nodes().each(function (r) {
                r.style.display = collapsed ? 'none' : '';
            });    

            // Add category name to the <tr>. NOTE: Hardcoded colspan
            return $('<tr/>')
                .append('<td colspan="8">' + group + ' (' + rows.count() + ')</td>')
                .attr('data-name', group)
                .toggleClass('collapsed', collapsed);
        }
      },
      processing : true,
      //retrieve: true,
      destroy: true,
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      // Declare the use of the extension in the dom parameter
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      // Configure the buttons
      buttons: [],
      columnDefs: [],
      responsive: false,
      scrollX: true,
      drawCallback: function ( settings ) {
        var api = this.api();
        var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
        var last=null; 

        api.column(3 /*this is index of column that you want to make group on it*/ , {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
        

            if ( last !== group ) {
                $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                    '<tr style="background-color:#dedede" class="group"><th colspan="5">'+group+'</th></tr>'
                ); 
                last = group;
            }
        });
     }
};
```

I receive the error below:

> **Type '{ order: (string | number)[][]; rowGroup: { dataSrc: number; startRender: (rows: any, group: any) => JQuery; }; processing: true; destroy: true; pagingType: string; ... 5 more ...; drawCallback: (settings: SettingsLegacy) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'Settings'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'rowGroup' does not exist in type 'Settings'.**

Note: My html page similar to example that I've mentioned with below header :

```
<table id="example" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" dt-instance="dtInstance" class="table-bordered compact cell-border compact stripe hover" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
```

**Update:**
I added the required plugins in **angular.json**

```
"styles": [
    ...
    "node_modules/datatables.net-rowgroup-dt/css/rowGroup.dataTables.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
    ...
    "node_modules/datatables.net-rowgroup-dt/js/rowGroup.dataTables.min.js"
]
```